# Django transform lat lon models to one pointfield and serialize it via geojson

Tags: json, django, geojson

My model

```
# GPS latitudes
latitudine = models.FloatField(max_length=50,default=None)
# GPS longitude
longitudine = models.FloatField(max_length=50,default=None)
# GEOJson
point = models.PointField(srid=4326, geography=True, null=True)
```

is there any way to create or pass lat long data to GEOjson model?

```
"features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "latitudine": "45.0717383",
                "longitudine": "7.6810848"
            },
            "geometry": null
        },
```

so all data from feature will go to geometry field?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but your geojson should look like this:

```
{
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "properties":{
        "latitudine":"45.0717383",
        "longitudine":"7.6810848"
      },
      "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
          7.6810848,
          45.0717383
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can validate it with http://geojson.io/ and other tools.